# What the...? Question about an approved edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I just got prompted with this suggested edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits#suggested-edits/4502836?&_suid=139663221440604793011885854138

It was approved.  How?  Is it me, or did the guy basically re-write the question and add a bunch of code the OP didn't even use?

If I'm missing something, please tell me so I know for future reference.

Comment: Wow. That code really came out of the blue. Same homework by a different person? And yes, I'd reject.

Comment: Give him a break.

Comment: The suggested edit queue is an uphill battle. I have given up on it precisely for this reason: robo reviewers (2700-500 are dangerous stats) and new users who don't know how things work (20-3 and 16-0). Sometimes you get lucky and have some good co-reviewers but it's really a coinflip. I wouldn't put too much thought in it when your rejection got approved. It's when your approval got rejected, that's when you have to worry.